# Absent a formal policy, is it rude to use a mobile phone to take notes in lectures and seminars?

Tags: lecture-notes

I like to use my iPhone to take notes in lectures and seminars. I prefer it to using paper (easy to lose, hard to search, bad for the environment) or a laptop (cumbersome to carry and loud to type with).

However, I get the impression that many people are against the use of phones in lectures for any purpose. As an undergraduate, I remember some lecturers publicly shaming people who used their phones, even when they were making notes or looking up something relevant to the lecture. One lecturer in particular even brought a jug of water to the class with her, and threatened that if she saw anyone with a phone she would put it in the jug. Admittedly phones can be used for irrelevant or distracting purposes, but this is also true of laptops and paper! I am now an academic myself, but still worry about offending colleagues.

Is it acceptable to use a phone to make notes in a lecture? If not, what makes them particularly unacceptable/rude compared with a laptop or tablet? And are there any strategies that can be used to indicate to a lecturer that you are using your phone to make notes (and not to make Tik Tok videos)?

Note, I am **not** asking for advice about whether taking notes on an iPhone is wise, nor about whether a "no phone policy" would be a good idea (the latter point is discussed [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/101419/should-i-ban-electronic-devices-smartphones-tablets-and-laptops-from-a-course/101429)).

Comment: You should indicate which country your question refers to, as there are legal implications in different places to this question.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112280/discussion-on-question-by-d-greenwood-using-a-mobile-phone-to-take-notes-in-lect).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I ban electronic devices (smartphones, tablets and laptops) from a course?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/101419/should-i-ban-electronic-devices-smartphones-tablets-and-laptops-from-a-course)

Answer (score 6):

Phones are not perceived as note-taking tools, making them undesirable in education and business settings. Laptops are tolerated in both settings, but don't expect respect. Tablets are perhaps the lesser-evil, especially when used with a stylus. Better still, specialised note-taking devices (not dissimilar to tablets) are now available. Paper will serve you well and set the best impression.